# Formula to look up values from multiple Non-Contiguous ranges

Tags: excel-formula

I have a lot of arrays in a sheet, all the arrays are the same size. The top left cell contains Array plus a number which is unique to that array, so the first array will have Array 1 in the top left corner. Underneath that each array has two random numbers, for example 2, 3.

In a separate sheet, I have a table with the Array numbers across the top, and the random numbers going down. And were the column for the array name, and row for the number intersect, I need the value of a cell to the right in the same row as the number, in the array.

For example in the table below I would need to find the value 7, given Array 1 and number 2. And if there is not data, It needs to write False, or none or something similar.
On the data sheet there are 70 arrays, and 40 different number, with each array containing 6 numbers.

<kbd>Array 1</kbd>                  
<kbd>2</kbd>      <kbd>0</kbd>      <kbd>7</kbd>      
<kbd>3</kbd>      <kbd>0</kbd>       <kbd>8</kbd>      
<kbd>Array 2</kbd>                  
<kbd>7</kbd>      <kbd>0</kbd>      <kbd>7</kbd>      
<kbd>9</kbd>      <kbd>0</kbd>       <kbd>8</kbd>      
<kbd>Array 3</kbd>                  
<kbd>12</kbd>      <kbd>0</kbd>      <kbd>7</kbd>      
<kbd>88</kbd>      <kbd>0</kbd>       <kbd>8</kbd>

Comment: show us desired output. Show us what you have so far

Comment: Next example could be : For `Array 3`, `number 88` you want to return `8` ?

Answer (score 0):

This formula should do the trick :
`=VLOOKUP(H2;OFFSET(INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(G2;A:A;0));1;0;2;3);3;FALSE)`
Presuming the data is set like this :
[image: Vlookup formula for many arrays]

Answer (score 0):

An array formula would do the trick with `INDEX MATCH`.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,MATCH($G2&$H2,A:A&A:A,0)),"FALSE OR SOMETHING SIMILAR")
```

After you have written this you need to press and hold *CTRL SHIFT* and click *ENTER*. This will make the formula an array and add {curly brackets}